# C# WPF - ComboBox, Values change but SelectedItem not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I know there are a lot questions about the SelectedItem and the ComboBox out there but it seems that they do not solve my problem.

I have a ComboBox where I bind a ObservableCollection of View Models and a TextBox which binds to the Description of the singe View models. I want to change the entries here... Everything works fine when i use the text box, the items will be changed in the ComboBox (even the selected one), but when i change the text in the code behind only the ComboBox List will be updated but not the current selected Value/Item.

My ComboBox looks like this at the moment:

```xaml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sports, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSport, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="365" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="30" Margin="5 5 5 5">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The used ViewModel looks like this:

```C#
public class SportViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DisciplineViewModel> _disciplinesProperty;

    public Sport Model
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return Model.Description; }
        set
        {
            if (Model.Description != value)
            {
               Model.Description = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => Description);
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DisciplineViewModel> Disciplines
    {
        get { return _disciplinesProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_disciplinesProperty != value)
            {
                _disciplinesProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Disciplines);
            }
        }
    }

    public SportViewModel(Sport source)
    {
       Model = source;
       Disciplines = new ObservableCollection<DisciplineViewModel>();
       foreach(Discipline d in Model.Disciplines)
       {
           Disciplines.Add(new DisciplineViewModel(d, this));
       }
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       if (obj == null || !(obj is SportViewModel))
           return false;

      return ((SportViewModel)obj).Description == this.Description;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      return base.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

and is used here:

```C#
class EditSportsDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  ...
  public ObservableCollection<SportViewModel> Sports 
  {
      get { return _sportsProperty; }
      set
      {
          if (_sportsProperty != value)
          {
              _sportsProperty = value;
          }
      } 
  }

  public SportViewModel SelectedSport
  {
      get { return _selectedSportPorperty; }
      set
      {
          if (_selectedSportPorperty != value)
          {
              if (value != null)
              {
                  Disciplines = value.Disciplines;
              }
              _selectedSportPorperty = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSport);
          }
      }
  }

  private void SportRevertExecuted()
  {
      if (SelectedSport != null)
      {
          _context.Entry(SelectedSport.Model).Reload();
      }
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSport.Description);
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSport);
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Sports);
      RaisePropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

The describtion is also changed by the one TextBox which works just fine

```xaml
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedSport.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="410"/>
```

But when I call `SportRevertExecuted()` only the item in the list of the ComboBox will be changed but not the "Text" of the currently selected Item. Maybe someone can help me here, I've tried a lot until now, nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved. Was quite stupid `RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSport.Description);` doesn't work as i thought. I've introduced a Method `UpdateView()` in SportViewModel which raises the PropertyChanged Event in the right Object, now everything works just fine.